# Vector of 20,000 small objects vs vector of 20,000 object pointers to 20,000 heap objects

Tags: c++, macos, optimization, memory-management, stl

Developing a 32-bit C++/carbon app under OS X Snow Leopard, ran into a problem where an stl vector of approximately 20,000 small objects (72 bytes each) was failing during a reallocation.  Seems the vector, which was several megabytes in size, couldn't expand to a contiguous piece of memory, which at the point of failure was only 1.2 MB in size.

```
GuardMalloc[Appname-33692]: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region

GuardMalloc[Appname-35026]: Failed to VM allocate 894752 bytes
GuardMalloc[ Appname-35026]: Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!

#0    0x00a30da8 in GMmalloc_zone_malloc_internal
#1    0x00a31710 in GMmalloc
#2    0x94a54617 in operator new
#3    0x0026f1d3 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<DataRecord>::allocate at new_allocator.h:88
#4    0x0026f1f8 in std::_Vector_base<DataRecord, std::allocator<DataRecord> >::_M_allocate at stl_vector.h:117
#5    0x0026f373 in std::vector<DataRecord, std::allocator<DataRecord> >::_M_insert_aux at vector.tcc:275
#6    0x0026f5a6 in std::vector<DataRecord, std::allocator<DataRecord> >::push_back at stl_vector.h:610
```

I can think of several strategies:

1) Reserve() a really, really big vector as soon as the app launches.  However, this assumes the user might not load additional files that contribute to this vector, pushing it beyond the pre-allocated limit and possibly getting back into the same situation.

2) Change the vector of objects/memory allocations into a vector of pointers to objects/memory allocations.  Clearly makes the vector itself a more manageable size, but then creates 20,000 small objects (which could eventually become like 50,000 objects, depending on what additional files the user loads).  Does this create a gigantic overhead problem?

3)  Change from a vector to a list, which may have its own overhead issues.

The vector is being constantly iterated through, and generally only appended to.

Any sage thoughts on these issues?

===============

ADDITIONAL NOTE: this particular vector just holds all imported record, so they can be indexed and sorted by ANOTHER vector that contains a sort order.  Once an item is put into this vector, it stays there for the lifetime of the app (also helps support undo operations by making sure the index into the vector always remains the same for that particular object).

Comment: Any chance of making it a 64 bit app - Carbon is depreciated so you will need to change in a reasonable short time.

Comment: @Mark: do you mean "deprecated"? I suppose Carbon is depreciating as well.

Comment: can you split the vector to many vectors ? `vector<vector<A>*> VoV[100];` fill `Vov[0]`, and  the `push_back` fails. begin to fill `VoV[1]`. and so on. is this suitable ? or it is too much work to handle the data in more than one structure(sorting, searching, ...). by the way you can create your own function doing this... im too optimistic

Comment: @outis - no it's not!  You seen the price o'gas?

Comment: @user516545 (you might want to pick a meaningful name): what is the relevant importance of the various operations on collections (e.g. adding, removing, random access, iteration)? Is there a natural ordering on the objects? A little more [background detail](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) would be helpful.

Comment: @Mark: yes, Carbon is just about dead.  Massive app, and for this release can't go Cocoa.  But nice thought.  (p.s. I know one can write a non-UI 64 thread, too)

Comment: @outis - OK, sorry -- name has been made more meaningful.  ALSO -- see my ADDITIONAL NOTE (above).

Answer (score 3):

I think a `std::deque` would be more suitable than a `std::list` or a `std::vector` in your case. `std::list` is not efficient in iteration or random indexing, while `std::vector` is slow to resize (as you have observed).  A `std::deque` does not need large amounts of memory when resizing, at the cost of slightly slower random indexing than a vector.

Comment: While `list` may have cache locality issues when iterating relative to `vector`, the real problem is if you need to index into a `list`, not iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use continuous storage like a `vector`. Go for a `deque` or `list` and the reallocations will not fail anymore.

If you really need high performance, consider writing your own container (ie ArrayList).

Comment: `std::deque` is a good idea, `std::list` wouldn't work as he needs to access the records by index.

Comment: What are you suggesting for the performance of `ArrayList`?  What would you recommend for performance over a `std::deque`?

Answer (score 1):

if even in the heap, there is not enough contigous space, use `deque`;
deque allocate not contigous space when it is needed. so it could handle the limit of 1.2 MB

`deque`  is made of some number of blocks of memory not only one contigous space. that s why it could work. but it is not sure(/totaly safe) because you dont control the behaviour of the deque.

see [this](http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/25090/dynamic-memory-allocation-fragmentation-c.html)about memory fragmentation (following is copy/paste from the web page): 
http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/25090/dynamic-memory-allocation-fragmentation-c.html :

Memory Fragmentation

The best way to understand memory fragmentation is to look at an example. For this example, it is assumed hat there is a 10K heap. First, an area of 3K is requested, thus:

```
     #define K (1024)
     char *p1;
     p1 = malloc(3*K);
```

Then, a further 4K is requested:

```
    p2 = malloc(4*K);
```

3K of memory is now free.

Some time later, the first memory allocation, pointed to by p1, is de-allocated:

```
    free(p1);
```

This leaves 6K of memory free in two 3K chunks. A further request for a 4K allocation is issued:

```
   p1 = malloc(4*K);
```

This results in a failure – NULL is returned into p1 – because, even though 6K of memory is available, there is not a 4K contiguous block available. This is memory fragmentation.

this is an issue even for kernels using virtual memory such as osx.

Comment: outis :  dont you have social abilities ? crual thinking outis.

Comment: It's nothing personal. SO has a very specific format: Q&A. Read the FAQs if you don't understand why my previous comment is relevant.

Comment: your previous comment is not relevant. i answered the question. the begining of the sentence "i vote for..." is kindness formula from me. it is an evidence i did not gamble. i give my answer which is correct.

Comment: It's not relevant to the answer as it stands, given the edits, but it's still relevant to what counts as an appropriate answer on SO. Moreover, it was relevant when I posted both previous comments. "I vote for" doesn't project kindness in English. It's hedging your answer so you don't have to support it. If you have good enough reasons behind your answer, you don't have to [equivocate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word).

Comment: you have bad oriented mind. i supported all my answer as gave code and explanation. for a non bad oriented mind : i completly engage myself to my response when i say "i vote for...". thats enough abusing my time and my patience.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6241/discussion-between-outis-and-eharvest)

Comment: @eharvest - When you say, "if even in the HEAP, there is not enough contiguous space..."  this implies that on OS X I can allocate memory in a different area than the heap?  I thought I had one big heap that was the maximum available memory space allocated to the app.  If not, then perhaps there's the answer?

Comment: @SMGreenfield: There's static/global objects, and function local objects as well as the heap, but they aren't useful in your case.

Comment: @SMGreenfield : the memory could be fragmented, so you can not get 4MB vector but two 2MB vectors.in addition, an hypothesis is when a vector uses all his avaible memory after several push_back, the vector ask for a bigger block of memory. so maybe , the vector copy all its content to the second block of memory... so there must be two big blocks of memory availble in the heap, the old and the new. it is an hypothesis. see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/vector_vs_deque.aspx. so test deque  or if you can use an array of vector* to see how much memory more than 1.2MB you can get in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Out of your three options, 1 doesn't seem like a guaranteed solution, while 2 adds complexity and the vector still has to grow.

Option 3 seems somewhat reasonable (or possibly use a `deque` as mentioned in another answer) because while it's semantically similar to option 2, it provides a more normalized method of allocating a new data object. Of course this assumes that you only append data and don't need random access.

However all that said I find it incredible that your program has fragmented memory so badly that on reasonably modern hardware it can't allocate 1.2MB of memory. Far more likely is that there's some undefined behavior lurking (or possibly a memory leak) in your program causing it to behave in this way, failing to allocate the memory. You could use valgrind to help hunt down what may be going on. Does the same problem happen when you use the builtin `new` and `delete` rather than `GMalloc`?

Is your program being `ulimit`ed to only have access to a small amount of memory?

Finally, if valgrind finds nothing and your program really is fragmenting memory horribly, I would consider stepping back and reconsidering your approach. You may want to evaluate an alternate approach that doesn't rely on millions(?) of allocations (I just can't see a small number of allocations fragmenting the heap that much).

Comment: ulimit is limited under OS X to be maximum file size.  Regarding fragmentation, this was my first thought, but as best I can tell memory fragmentation is NOT an issue with the way memory is allocated on OS X.